# app crashed wiht classes.dex permission denied error

Tags: android, permission-denied

My app is crashed with following error,

```
 E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file:/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.stvgame.xiaoy.remote-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
```

And our app use mutipule dex, does they have relation?

Comment: I get the same error, without multidex. I do have arm8 build though, maybe it is a 64bit specific thing?

Comment: I solved this problem with edit my primary dex file. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294318/failed-to-create-oat-file)

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem and my solution was disable the Instant Run, if you're using Android Studio...

Comment: And how to you disable instant run ?

Answer (score 4):

I had got a similar error when i used multi dex for the first time,
[This](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) guide helped a lot,

My error was i forgot to add this in the application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

in your build gradle, make sure you have included the following lines:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Even then multi dex has limitations with progaurd, read the guide to find out if that is causing this issue.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, still get errors in logcat

Comment: @Jarrette, remove both ** characters near compile and multiDexEnabled true